# Core Data Saving Attributes Of Entities

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, fetch

This question is about Core Data.

I created a Entity called **TV** with three attributes called **name**, **price** and **size**. I also created a subclass of NSMutableObject with **TV.h** and **TV.m** files.

I imported the **TV.h** to my **DetailViewController.h** which handles my sliders und UIElements I want to take the values of.

So I did a fetch request, and everything works fine, **BUT**:

Everytime I update the UISlider (valueDidChange:), Xcode creates a **COPY** of my entity and adds it to my **TV-Object**.

All I want Xcode is just to **edit and save to the current entity**, not to **edit and save in a new entity**.

Help is very appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

My Code:

`DetailViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)collectSliderValue:(UISlider *)sender {

if (__managedObjectContext == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Problem ...");
    __managedObjectContext = [(MasterViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"... solved!");
}

if (sender == sizeSlider) {

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TV" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    TV * currentTV = [[TV alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    currentTV.size = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(sender.value + 0.5f)];
    currentTV.name = @"New TV!";

    NSError *error11;
    [__managedObjectContext save:&error11];

    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Name = %@", [info valueForKey:@"name"]);
        NSLog(@"Size = %@", [info valueForKey:@"size"]);
        NSLog(@"Price = %@", [info valueForKey:@"price"]);
    }
    [fetchRequest release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Editing begins ...     
TV * currentTV = [[TV alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Editing doesn't begin, you are creating a new object right there. Your view controller needs an instance variable to hold the current `TV` entity that you are modifying.

From the template project you have created, the variable `detailItem` contains the managed object that you are currently editing. You should specifically set this as a `TV` object, and refer to this instead of `currentTV` in your detailViewController code. You must *remove all of the fetch request and managed object context code* - this is not relevant in your detail view controller, it should be managed by the master view controller.

So, in DetailViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
```

becomes

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) TV detailItem;
```

And in your collectSliderValue method, it should look something much more simple like this:

```
- (IBAction)collectSliderValue:(UISlider *)sender 
{

    if (sender == sizeSlider) 
        self.detailItem.size = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value];    
}
```

The saving of the managed object context shouldn't occur until back in your detail view controller, this is taken care of in your application delegate.

In your master detail controller .m file you may also need to import the TV.h file so that it knows that TV is a `NSManagedObject` subclass. Also, cast to TV when you are setting the detail item:

```
self.detailViewController.detailItem = (TV*)selectedObject;
```

Comment: Thanks so far. Whats the code to "hold the current TV entity I am modifying"? Or: How can I initialize my `TV`entity without creating a new one?

Comment: Thanks so far. I edited my post. Yes, thats the only place. The aim is to store a slider value by change and to set the slider at this value after restarting the program. Maybe it helps: I worked with Apples Core Data Template (iPad) with the UISplitView.

Comment: It's difficult to describe, also because I am not a native speaker ... I would recommend to open a new Xcode Project, Choose iPad and SplitView Template with checked boxes on "Use Storyboard" and "Use CoreData". Then you are on my setup. Basically the template adds a new object by button click. (UIBarButtonItem) and shows it in a table view. I just want to update __this__ entity with my slider. I already changed the attribute's type from `NSDate`to `NSNumber`and added two other attributes like I said. It all works fine but there's this saving problem ... Thanks so far!

Comment: I'll give it a go - might not be for a few hours, though :) Wouldn't have guessed you weren't a native speaker, your English is excellent.

Comment: Hey jr! Thank you for your compliment and pointing out `id detailItem`. It seems to work out quite well (at least with a few optimizations for sure ;-) ). I'll test now if the object is really saved globally or if its just a local change. There is one last error message I get in `masterViewController.m`: `Semantic Issue - Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'TV *' from 'NSManagedObject *'` at this line `self.detailViewController.detailItem = selectedObject;` Thanks again! This site lives from people like you who do great solutions in a short period of time! :)

Comment: OK jr, I tested it. The `semantic issue` is still there but the rest works like a charm. **Thank you, you made my day! :)** (I would vote your answer up but: Darwin.rep < 15 ... ;-) )

Comment: The semantic issue is probably due to the defaults in the template code that assume your fetch request is returning an NSManagedObject - see further update.

Comment: This one did it. Thank you. No build issues. :)

Comment: OK, I found another problem. If I create a few new Object, I can work with them, change between them etc. Everything works. But if a close the app completely (in the iOS5 Multitasking Bar) and open it up again, I got the objects I created, but the attributes are set to the standard values. That is the case with all objects except of one: The one which stands on top of the list. Did I forget a save command anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: This should be a new question.

Comment: I set up the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049696/coredata-saving-object-changes-by-quit). Thanks so far jr! You helped me a lot!